# Does gmail has getproflie api to fetch users profile and not profile of contact

Tags: user-profile, gmail-api

Does gmail has getproflie api to fetch users profile(I don't need profile of contact present in gmail account). https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/ does not ahve any profile api.

Comment: In one of our app we do use getcontact for gmail we use /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not, the Gmail API is designed to manage emails in Gmail.